# Error ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH

Tags: android, linux, cordova

I have installed **Ubuntu 14.1 X86_64** when I run `sudo cordova build` the following message appears:

```
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/infra/workspaces/mobileprojectsap/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
```

in my `.bash_profile` I have:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/infra/MyPrograms/android-sdk-linux
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

when I run

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

appears `/home/infra/MyPrograms/android-sdk-linux`

I need to do something else? any ideas?

Thank

alejo

Comment: Sudo doesn't uses your user infra environmental variables but sudo user environmental variables. Try to execute `sudo echo $ANDROID_HOME` and you'll probably see that the variable is not set. Do you really need to run cordova build using sudo? Why? Remember that you can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31463063/edit) to add more info.

Answer (score 0):

Just run your `cordova build` without the `sudo`. Using root user overrides your `.bash_profile` and thus the *ANDROID_HOME* is not set appropriately.

In case the root access is actually needed, change to root with command `su` and edit the Bash profile there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use `sudo`? The issue here is that your environment variables are not available when you`sudo` unless you specify the `-E` option to `sudo`.

See [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo#Environment_variables) for details of how to preserve your environment variables either using `sudo -E` or doing

```
sudo visudo
Defaults env_keep += "ANDROID_HOME"
```

Answer (score 0):

I run `sudo echo $ANDROID_HOME` and the variable is no set.
I run `cordova build` and it worked well.
I am new to using linux.
Thank you very much everyone for the quick response